# Wordpress query regarding creating admin login

Tags: wordpress

I have a question regarding creating a WordPress site:
* Is it possible to create admin login and user login from WordPress? (and when I mean admin login, I don't mean the backend of the site.)

- I need admin login to the website where only the admin can enter posts via a form and a submit button and user login can view those posts and comment on them. SO basically I need a different UI for the admin to add and edit posts.

Any suggestions for easy ways?

Comment: You should get familiar with the WordPress [Roles and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities). Granted it's not an easy read but you will thank yourself later for taking the time to get familiar with this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: mark those posts / pages as PRIVATE.

Comment: Yes that I can understand. What im talking about is, is it possible to create a page where the admin login can add new items into the website (not from the backend) ?